# Repeat a step in a for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I have a for loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
            var gridResult = Math.floor(Math.random() * 77) + 1;
            $(['data-x='+gridResult+']').append('<div></div>');
        }

<html>
<div class="grid" data-x="0"></div>
...
<div class="grid" data-x="77"></div>
```

Now I want it to repeat the step, if it detects that there was allready an element assigned in one of the previous iterations, so there won't be 2 divs assigned to the same element.

I tried doing that by using:

```
if ($(this).children().length > 1) {
                    return;
                }
```

but that didn't work out since there were still elements with 2 divs attached.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please append your html, without it's hard to understand what you are trying to achive

Comment: To repeat a step in the loop you've got, decrement `i` again: `i--`. However it's not at all clear what you mean by 'if it detects that there was already an element assigned in one of the previous iterations by random chance'

Comment: Pedantry note: "Iterating for loop" - for loops are by their nature always iterating.

Comment: Edited the question, I hope it's more easily readable now

Comment: Thanks for editing, I added an answer for you

Comment: you can repeat the step, or you could change the way you produce `gridResult` so that it doesn't produce duplicates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve your goal you can add the `if` condition within the loop. If a child element is found within the target you can decrement 1 from `i` to force the loop to repeat again. Try this:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
  var gridResult = Math.floor(Math.random() * 77) + 1;
  let $target = $(['data-x=' + gridResult + ']');
    if ($target.children().length) {
      i--; // repeat the action
    } else {
      $target.append('<div></div>');
    }
  }
}
```